# Activity.java in Android Studio error

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

So I just created an app and the `MainActivity.java` already has compiler errors:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);

    mVisible = true;
    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
```

The error is

> cannot resolve symbol 'r'

I saw this question [can not resolve R in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348824/can-not-resolve-r-in-android-studio) , but it cleaning and rebuilding my project did not yeild any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of Possible Solution

**Solution 1:**

`Clean` and `Rebuild` the Project

**Solution 2 :**

Close Android Studio and Open Again.

**Solution 3 :**

Try `Invalidate caches and Restart` and select `Restart` option.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens sometimes. Happened to me quite a few times. I just restarted the project and Synchronized the Gradle (Sync Project with Gradle Files) and it went back to normal. Try that. It may work for you as well.

Comment: Dear Dev. This question already asked on Here .Please give link instead of Same answer .

Answer (score 0):

you could re-start all(android studio,cache,system). it will recover.

Comment: Dear Dev. This question already asked on Here .Please give link instead of Same answer .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the peoblem caused by "junit test" package. See this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410648/5780236